# display selected nodes on page load using dxTreeList

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, devextreme, treelistview

I am using devextreme dxTreeList and knockout js

[here is my exmple in codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMWGEb)
my questions is :
how to assign json data from web service to the `selectedRowKeys` 
my data is like

```
 $.getJSON('../DataAPI/api/Data/GetData', function (data) {
            self.GetData(JSON.parse(data));})
```

and the data comes like this

```
GetData (["2,8,25"])
```

I want the data comes like this

```
GetData ([2,8,25])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stringArray = data[0].split(",");
stringArray.forEach(function(string){
    selectedRowKeys.push(parseInt(string));
});
self.GetData(selectedRowKeys);
```

Comment: Welcome :) @Tamer Could you upvote the answer? It's the Up arrow next to my answer

Comment: I did but it gave me this message ( thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly display post score.)